# Is there anyway to combine taginput and autocomplete in buefy?

Tags: vue.js, bulma, buefy

in this app i'm building i need a taginput that uses autocomplete, using bulma and buefy and realy like [autocomplete](https://buefy.org/documentation/autocomplete) and [taginput](https://buefy.org/documentation/taginput) for that i wanna know is there anyway to combine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant as it was asked a while ago. But

If you take a look at

https://buefy.org/documentation/taginput

You will see that adding `autocomplete` to your b-taginput field will allow you to use the autocomplete features as properties in the same field of buefy alongside that of taginput.

Comment: no thats not the answer i want a Templated Autocomplete in taginput which i see it now, so tnx